# Spain and curse

Tags: history, geography, curse

Was there a Curse placed on Jews returning to Spain after the Spanish Inquisition if so who stated it and general background information would be appreciated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://home.earthlink.net/~bnahman/Alhambra_Decree_Abrabanels_Answer.htm

http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/654739/jewish/Is-there-a-ban-on-living-in-Spain.htm

Thess links confirm that there was no curse on Jews returning to Spain.

Comment: I don't see any mention of a curse on the Jews returning AFTER.